# use a function from other sikuli script

Tags: python, function, sikuli

I have one scripts say main.sikuli which is used in below script:--

```
from main.sikuli import *
class TestsMain(unittest.TestCase):

   def setUp(self): 

       wait(2)
       click("pica.png")
   def tearDown(self):


       if exists("b.png"):
           type(Key.F4,KeyModifier.CTRL)



   def testa(self):

       #function body
       main.testb(self)
```

where `testb` is a function in main.sikuli, but this does not work.

Please advise.

Answer (score 1):

From https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5806383/calling-sikuli-from-cpython:

> According to the Sikuli documentation it is not possible to run the .py files generated by Sikuli with CPython since it is domain-specific Jython code. Just the syntax is Python.
>   If you just need to call the script, a (silly) solution is described in
>   https://answers.launchpad.net/sikuli/+question/131729 :

```
    import subprocess
    import sys

    def RunSikuliScript(sikuliscriptname):
     subprocess.Popen('"C:\Program Files\Sikuli\Sikuli-ide.exe" -r ' + sikuliscriptname, shell=True)

    if __name__ == '__main__':
      RunSikuliScript(sys.argv[1])
```

tl;dr: you should probably use Jython